# Add 5 to whatever my shared preference is and put it into a textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

All I'm trying to do is add 5 'coins' if the player wins the level for the first time.
Here's what I've got.  It's under

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_winroundactivity);
    **initialize();**
}

private void initialize(){

SharedPreferences coin = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String newcoin = coin.getString("coin","");
    Double coinnum = 0.0;
    try {
        coinnum = Double.parseDouble(newcoin);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        **coinnum = 0;** // your default value
    }


    level = getSharedPreferences("level",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    levelunlock = getSharedPreferences("levelunlock",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (level.getString("level","").compareTo(levelunlock.getString("levelunlock","")) == 1) {
        levelunlock.edit().putString("levelunlock", (level.getString("level", ""))).apply();

        if (level.getString("level","").equals("2")){
            coin.edit().putString("coin",Double.toString(coinnum) + 5).apply();
            textviewcoinnum.setText(newcoin);
        }

    }
```

I've posted my code that works below. All of the credit to @tahsinRupam

Comment: Check the below answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
if (level.getString("level","").equals("2")){
   String prevCoin =  sharedPreferences.getString("coin", "");
   Double newCoin = Double.parseDouble(prevCoin) + 5;
   coin.edit().putString("coin", Double.toString(newCoin)).apply();
   textviewcoinnum.setText(coin.getString("coin",""));
   //supposed to add 5 coins and set set the new value as text in a textView.
}
```

**Update:** To check if you have a valid double value, do as following:

```
Double coinnum = 0.0;
try {
   coinnum = Double.parseDouble(newcoin);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   coinnum = 0; // your default value
}
```

Check your logcat if you get any `NumberFormatException`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Will try it out soon.  Thank you for your suggestion!  @tahsinRupam

Comment: No prob. Let it me know how it goes.

Comment: It does not like the Double.  App crashes on that activity with the error: invalid Double.  Few other errors i tried to fix too.  I've edited my post with some new code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is error log also the updated one ? If yes can you highlight the codes of 39 and 79 no. in winroundactivity.java please ? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Error log is updated.  Those lines have ** around them now.

Comment: Thank u for ur co-operation. This error is causing because your `newcoin` is not a valid double. It can be an empty string. You can set a try-catch around the code as above (my updated answer) to check if you've got a valid double value as string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141845/discussion-between-carter-ray-and-tahsinrupam).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works.  Most of the credit goes to @tahsinRupam

```
SharedPreferences coin = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String newcoin = coin.getString("coin","");
    double coinnum;
    try {
        coinnum = Double.parseDouble(newcoin);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        coinnum = 0;
    }


    level = getSharedPreferences("level",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    levelunlock = getSharedPreferences("levelunlock",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (level.getString("level","").compareTo(levelunlock.getString("levelunlock","")) == 1) {
        levelunlock.edit().putString("levelunlock", (level.getString("level", ""))).apply();

        if (level.getString("level","").equals("2")){
            coinnum = coinnum + 5;
            coin.edit().putString("coin",(Double.toString((coinnum)))).apply();
            newcoin = coin.getString("coin","");
            textviewcoinnum.setText(newcoin);
        }

    }
```